# What does this for (auto &x : ic)?

Tags: c++

What does this code do  for (auto &x : ic)? How can I write the same instruction but in the form
for ( init-expression ; cond-expression ; loop-expression )
 statement

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int j=0;
    vector<int> ic(n), fc(n);
    for (auto &x : ic)
        cin >> x;
    for (auto &x : fc)
        cin >> x;
}
```

Comment: Its exactly the same thing, basically you are using range based for loop and the variable x directly references a position in the vector instead of creating a copy of the value at a index.

Comment: @SamarthyaSingh But how can I rewrite this code sequence? I tried for (i = 0; i <n; i ++) {cin >> x;} and it doesn't do the same

Comment: @alexandraa `cin >> ic[i]`, similar for `fc` vector.

Comment: As @alexandraa said.